# not able to send reply sms using twilio sms services in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, twilio

Hi i had developed an application in .NET for where we can send sms to user and want user reply sms for that we are using Twilio sms service.
i had created the code for sending sms which is running perfectly but while user receive the sms he is not able to reply fro mobile bcz there is no number is available to reply only short code is available. 
so anyone having idea for twilio integration .. help required here

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.   Before I offer a suggestion, can you clarify:  you are using Twilio to send messages from a non-US based Short Code.  What country is the short code based in and what countries are you sending messages to?

Answer (score 2):

You should give us more context and some code...

However have you specified the Message URL? Check the [Twilio documentation](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages)

> By specifying an Message URL for your messaging enabled Twilio phone
>   number, Twilio will make a request to your application to notify you
>   when someone replies to a message you send. Twilio's request and your
>   corresponding response are covered in the Message portion of the TwiML
>   documentation

Comment: thanx for the reply but in my case problem is not that i already mention the URL,i read some where it  may be because the short code for the messaging is belong to other country and i am not in same country so this may the problem i am not getting reply option or number to reply.